# JavaScript get data from JSON and select values

Tags: javascript, json

Just starting in JavaScript, of course I apologize, I make a request for JSON data, I get it, I can’t really figure out how to filter out the received email with a .net domain and output only them to the console ... at least just give an example or what continue to do.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', false);
xhr.send();
 if (xhr.status != 200) {
      alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); 
} else {
   console.log(xhr.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your question with sample response and what kind of data you want in the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) api here instead of `XMLHttpRequest` as it has a more cleaner interface and provides an easy, logical way to fetch resources asynchronously across the network. After getting the response you can use array [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to get all the emails in an array and finally using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method filter out the received email with a `.net` domain:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const emails = data.map(d => d.email).filter(e => e.includes('.net'))
    console.log(emails);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the response to an object using `JSON.parse`, then go through each element checking if the email matches.

```js
responseText = `[{"id":1, "name":"Leanne Graham", "username":"Bret", "email":"Sincere@april.biz", "address":{"street":"Kulas Light", "suite":"Apt. 556", "city":"Gwenborough", "zipcode":"92998-3874", "geo":{"lat":"-37.3159", "lng":"81.1496"}}, "phone":"1-770-736-8031 x56442", "website":"hildegard.org", "company":{"name":"Romaguera-Crona", "catchPhrase":"Multi-layered client-server neural-net", "bs":"harness real-time e-markets"}}, {"id":2, "name":"Ervin Howell", "username":"Antonette", "email":"Shanna@melissa.tv", "address":{"street":"Victor Plains", "suite":"Suite 879", "city":"Wisokyburgh", "zipcode":"90566-7771", "geo":{"lat":"-43.9509", "lng":"-34.4618"}}, "phone":"010-692-6593 x09125", "website":"anastasia.net", "company":{"name":"Deckow-Crist", "catchPhrase":"Proactive didactic contingency", "bs":"synergize scalable supply-chains"}}, {"id":3, "name":"Clementine Bauch", "username":"Samantha", "email":"Nathan@yesenia.net", "address":{"street":"Douglas Extension", "suite":"Suite 847", "city":"McKenziehaven", "zipcode":"59590-4157", "geo":{"lat":"-68.6102", "lng":"-47.0653"}}, "phone":"1-463-123-4447", "website":"ramiro.info", "company":{"name":"Romaguera-Jacobson", "catchPhrase":"Face to face bifurcated interface", "bs":"e-enable strategic applications"}}, {"id":4, "name":"Patricia Lebsack", "username":"Karianne", "email":"Julianne.OConner@kory.org", "address":{"street":"Hoeger Mall", "suite":"Apt. 692", "city":"South Elvis", "zipcode":"53919-4257", "geo":{"lat":"29.4572", "lng":"-164.2990"}}, "phone":"493-170-9623 x156", "website":"kale.biz", "company":{"name":"Robel-Corkery", "catchPhrase":"Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity", "bs":"transition cutting-edge web services"}}, {"id":5, "name":"Chelsey Dietrich", "username":"Kamren", "email":"Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca", "address":{"street":"Skiles Walks", "suite":"Suite 351", "city":"Roscoeview", "zipcode":"33263", "geo":{"lat":"-31.8129", "lng":"62.5342"}}, "phone":"(254)954-1289", "website":"demarco.info", "company":{"name":"Keebler LLC", "catchPhrase":"User-centric fault-tolerant solution", "bs":"revolutionize end-to-end systems"}}, {"id":6, "name":"Mrs. Dennis Schulist", "username":"Leopoldo_Corkery", "email":"Karley_Dach@jasper.info", "address":{"street":"Norberto Crossing", "suite":"Apt. 950", "city":"South Christy", "zipcode":"23505-1337", "geo":{"lat":"-71.4197", "lng":"71.7478"}}, "phone":"1-477-935-8478 x6430", "website":"ola.org", "company":{"name":"Considine-Lockman", "catchPhrase":"Synchronised bottom-line interface", "bs":"e-enable innovative applications"}}, {"id":7, "name":"Kurtis Weissnat", "username":"Elwyn.Skiles", "email":"Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz", "address":{"street":"Rex Trail", "suite":"Suite 280", "city":"Howemouth", "zipcode":"58804-1099", "geo":{"lat":"24.8918", "lng":"21.8984"}}, "phone":"210.067.6132", "website":"elvis.io", "company":{"name":"Johns Group", "catchPhrase":"Configurable multimedia task-force", "bs":"generate enterprise e-tailers"}}, {"id":8, "name":"Nicholas Runolfsdottir V", "username":"Maxime_Nienow", "email":"Sherwood@rosamond.me", "address":{"street":"Ellsworth Summit", "suite":"Suite 729", "city":"Aliyaview", "zipcode":"45169", "geo":{"lat":"-14.3990", "lng":"-120.7677"}}, "phone":"586.493.6943 x140", "website":"jacynthe.com", "company":{"name":"Abernathy Group", "catchPhrase":"Implemented secondary concept", "bs":"e-enable extensible e-tailers"}}, {"id":9, "name":"Glenna Reichert", "username":"Delphine", "email":"Chaim_McDermott@dana.io", "address":{"street":"Dayna Park", "suite":"Suite 449", "city":"Bartholomebury", "zipcode":"76495-3109", "geo":{"lat":"24.6463", "lng":"-168.8889"}}, "phone":"(775)976-6794 x41206", "website":"conrad.com", "company":{"name":"Yost and Sons", "catchPhrase":"Switchable contextually-based project", "bs":"aggregate real-time technologies"}}, {"id":10, "name":"Clementina DuBuque", "username":"Moriah.Stanton", "email":"Rey.Padberg@karina.biz", "address":{"street":"Kattie Turnpike", "suite":"Suite 198", "city":"Lebsackbury", "zipcode":"31428-2261", "geo":{"lat":"-38.2386", "lng":"57.2232"}}, "phone":"024-648-3804", "website":"ambrose.net", "company":{"name":"Hoeger LLC", "catchPhrase":"Centralized empowering task-force", "bs":"target end-to-end models"}}]`;

var data = JSON.parse(responseText);
for (var el of data) {
  if (el.email.indexOf(".net") > 0) console.log(el.email);
}
```